# Java NullPointerException check on chained methods

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null

I want to check for a null pointer when accessing a field several classes deep (in a chain of get methods). However, if one of the earlier methods is `null` I get a `NullPointerException` anyways.

This is what I want to check, though it can still get a `NullPointerException`:

```
if(x.getLocation().getBuilding().getSolidFuelInd() != null)
            pol.setWood_heat_ind(x.getLocation().getBuilding().getSolidFuelInd() ? "Y" : "N");
```

This the behavior I want the above code to exhibit:

```
if(x.getLocation() != null)
    if(x.getLocation().getBuilding() != null)
        if(x.getLocation().getBuilding().getSolidFuelInd() != null)
            pol.setWood_heat_ind(x.getLocation().getBuilding().getSolidFuelInd() ? "Y" : "N");
```

The field on the pol is optional and should only be set if the above getter is not `null`. However the building and location objects could also be `null`, so now I must check to that they're valid.

Is there any sort of shorter way to check all the above like I want?

Comment: Why don't you enclose your first solution in `try catch NPE` block?

Comment: I could, but I feel try/catches are meant to handle errors in the code. Getting a null pointer would not be atypical behavior.

Comment: It's also not much cleaner than my second code snippet. I know how to handle the error, I was just looking for an easier, more attractive way to do so.

Comment: @tfbbt8 sounds like you just need to change your view of try/catch, as it's very appropriate here. Try/catch let's you handle exceptions. Exceptions can be thrown for all sorts of purposes, not just errors.

Comment: in groovy its just x?.location?.building?.solidFuelInd, but java is too conservative

Answer (score 6):

With Java 8's `Optional<>` class, you can `map` a value as so:

```
Optional.of(x)
    .map(ClassOfX::getLocation)
    .map(Location::getBuilding)
    .map(Building::getSolidFuelInd)
    .map(solidFuelInd -> solidFuelInd ? "Y" : "N")
    .ifPresent(pol::setWood_heat_ind);
```

`map` calls will only be executed if the value of the optional isn't `null` thus avoiding the `NullPointerException`.
`ifPresent`'s purpose is to call your `setWood_heat_ind` only if a value if available.

A nice single-call equivalent to null checks.

Answer (score 2):

If its code reduction you want then you can save each call in a variable.

```
// note: Replace type with the correct type
type location = x.getLocation();
type building = location == null ? null : location.getBuilding();

// note: you don't have to check for null on primitive types 
pol.setWood_heat_ind(building != null && building.getSolidFuelInd() ? "Y" : "N");
```

This is much cleaner and easier to follow.

Food for thought, you don't check for `null` on primitive types `boolean, int, byte` etc. so the last `null` check on `building.getSolidFuelInd()` is not needed

Answer (score 1):

Java 8 has `Optional<T>` which would make for one chained expression, though verbose.

However Java 8 also has `Stream<T>` and you could have a 
"stream" of 0 or 1 item, and then query with lambdas.

```
x.getLocation()
    .map((loc) -> loc.getBuilding())
    .map((building) -> building.getSolidFuelInd() != null)
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent ...
```

Or

```
x.getLocation()
    .map(Location::getBuilding)
    .map(Building::getSolidFuelInd())
    .filter(fuelInd -> fuelId != null)
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent ...
```

It probably will be a matter of slow coming to terms with an application of those new terms.

Answer (score 0):

You could just catch the exception

```
    try{
        pol.setWood_heat_ind(x.getLocation().getBuilding().getSolidFuelInd() ? "Y" : "N");
    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        //e.printStackTrace(); or whatever you want
    }
```

(Referring to your possible solution) checking for the returned values implies invoking the same methods more the once, that's why I would use this solution.

As Jay Harris pointed out, you can obviously check the values and save the return parameter, without having to invoke the same method again. You can do it in many different ways, here one

```
    Object loc=null,build=null;

    Boolean SFI = ((loc=x.getLocation())==null?null:
                   ((build=loc.getBuilding())==null?null:
                       (build.getSolidFuelInd())));

    if(SFI!=null)pol.setWood_heat_ind(SFI?"Y":"N");
```

But is it worth it? I made this more complicated than it could on purpose, but anyway, why doing that if you can `try...catch` in two simple lines?

Comment: I could, but I feel try/catches are meant to handle errors in the code. Getting a null pointer would not be atypical behavior.

Comment: That's true, but notice how your possible solution, if values other than null are always returned, has 9 methods invocations. In this way you can be sure that the minimum amount of invokation is performed

Comment: This does not seem like a good trade-off to me. constructing an exception with stack trace will likely be a lot more expensive than calling a few getters twice.

Comment: @NathanHughes I know that's not the perfect solution, I would avoid checking for null values both for stilistic reasons and performance. Maybe behind every *get()* method data is evaluated,  filtered and checked in some way, resulting in slower execution. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: In this example I would remove the `e.printStackTrace();` since you know what the exception is; you could replace it with `pol.setWood_heat_ind("N");` or other logic you want to have

Comment: I agree that in my case the catch would just be empty because I wouldn't want to do anything with it. Performance difference is negligible and isn't really a concern. I guess the answer is either a try/catch or a long if statement. Whichever you choose is up to you. I feel like my first code snippet is a trivial check. Java should add that if a previous object is null, that the whole method chain would return null and the check would work as intended.

Comment: @tfbbt8 you can refer to my solution if you don't want to use try catches

Comment: Your last statement, how is that possible when the return value is stored and never called again?